# How to install/ solve No model pkg-resource issue python

Tags: python, pip

I have multiple issue

**First issue:**

I have a server which is so secure that is running
`REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7"`
`REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.4`

There is no internet connectivity there and I want to download some packages like

1. pysnmp
2. pandas
3. numpy
4. psutil
5. some others

As per my research, the best way to download from server that has internet and transfer the file to the server that does not have an internet.

I tried of things, like download tar.gz of the package or use basket or take full package but no use

**Second issue:**

While I am trying, I am getting `No module named pkg_resources error`.Hhow can I solve that first in-order to proceed?

my python version is

python2 is 2.7.5
python3 is 3.4.9

i am tried pip install pysnmp-4.4.12.tar.gz to the main package. it mention to be no Module pk_resource.

i tried also to use basket as per the website https://pythonhosted.org/Basket/
and i used easy_install -f ~/.basket -H None pyramid
and i got pkg_resource module error.

However When i download setuptools through the website https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/0.9.8/#installation-instructions

and i use python eazy-setup.py --user the Error is
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/XlsxWriter-1.1.2.dist-info'

Updated !!!!

I managed to do it Thanks for the help

Comment: Please be more specific: `but no use` -> why? what error message do you get? `No module named pkg_resources error` what command are you trying here and what is the **full** error message?

Comment: Please add these infos to your question by using the `edit` button. Then you can also copy paste the **full** error of your commands

Answer (score 0):

I the problem is dependency tree i suggest running a local pip server : https://pypi.org/project/pypiserver/

and copy all needed package to server you can see it with:

```
pip freeze
```

and install your package with:

```
pip install --extra-index-url http://localhost:8080/simple/
```

Answer (score 0):

so Here is the solution!!

For this problem:
No module named pkg_resources error 
i was using pip install pysnmp or pip install pandas

i should use python -m pip install

the second issue :

the Error is [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/XlsxWriter-1.1.2.dist-info'

the solution is sudo python -m pip install

The main reasons is that secured Server is used to have multiple users ( Main user where main function is running)
so using sudo is important

Finally how to install package is easy.

Go to pypi and download
pandas-0.25.3-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl

then sudo python3 -m pip install pandas-0.25.3-cp36-cp36-manylinux1_x86_64.whl

some Tips:

try to use virtual machine like virtual box for testing how to install and once it is install try to browser for it. Why i am saying that because i am running Windows and my server is Redhat so any solution on my windows is useless so i had to use my laptop with virtual box ( I cant download Virtual box due security)

second thing, python is different than python3 so if you use python in your virtual box which is host Linux server , you will get pandas-0.25.3-cp27-cp27-manylinux1_x86_64.whl not pandas-0.25.3-cp36-cp36-manylinux1_x86_64.whl so becareful

and Last tip once you done use sudo python whateveryouwant torun.py

again why sudo because all of your packages are inside main file not inside your user

Hope i managed to answer my self correctly